# Slim pass class instance to $app

Tags: php, slim

```
<?php
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';

  // Include all controllers
  foreach(glob("controllers/*.php") as $controller)
  {
    include $controller;
  }

  // Instantiate a new Slip application
  $app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'debug' => true
  ));

  // HOME CONTROLLER
  $home = new Home;
  $vr = $home->index();

  // Register application routes
  $app->get('/', function () {
      echo $vr;
  });

  // Run application
  $app->run();
```

This is my controller I want to use controllers and not keep everything in this single file. Anyhow I have a controllers map where I keep all my controllers. I automatically include them all at start however I can't seem to pass `$home` variable to `get()` method so I could call `$vr` indede it or `$home->index()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass it to your function like this:

```
..., function () use($home){
  ...
```

<del>I think Slim also passes `$app` as the first argument to your function.</del>

**Edit:** actually it doesn't [according to its docs](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Application-Names-and-Scopes), so you'll have to pass that too inside the `use` statement (function arguments are URL parameters):

```
$app->get('/', function () use($home, $app) {
   $vr = $home->index();
   echo $vr;
   // $app is accesible too...
});
```

Comment: Hm, yes. This fixed my problem, quite so. Thank you chap. Now I can also pass $app instance to my controllers and use database class (R) and call $app->render() directly from my controllers.

Comment: Will you edit your answer to remove the incorrect code sample?  I see where you edited below the snippet to correct yourself, but the code sample really stands out.  I'd like to upvote your answer, but not while that sample is still there.